# How would I match a string that's not in HTML or [] tags?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm making a format function in PHP and want to use Regex to replace some words with links (`<a href>`). The only problem is that I want to exclude any occurrences within HTML tags or [] tags.

So these should not be replaced:

- `<span class='haha Test'> test </span>` (both)
- [test]
- [tag="test"]
- `<img src="/path/test.jpg" />`

These should be replaced:

- This is a test
- Test.Test. (both)
- This is [ a test ] and this is a "test" as well. (both)
- It could also have this [ as a test text. (unbalanced brackets)
- Maybe they've typed " test which should also work

I don't have control over the input. It only needs to replace the first occurence and it should ignore enters and whitespaces.

I've came quite far with this regex:
https://regexr.com/4nrpe

If any regex expert could help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You would use a html parsing tool like [dom document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and match on text nodes only, and then perform additional checks on your bracket syntax with regex.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @toto There is a link in the question, that's what i have tried.

Comment: Also @Scuzzy , The input is a multiline text, not just 1 line